# Solr scoring based on subdocument (parent blockjoin)

Tags: join, solr, solr-boost

I have the following structure of ... lets say products in a store. The Products have a rating. Then users can, additionally, rate the product (on their own). Lets say 300k Products plus 50k user-ratings (to each product)

Question 1: Are Subdocuments the right choice? I am adding everything with SolrJ, I did not find any other suitable method of doing that.

For sake of an example, you could copy and paste the following code to your collection:

```
<add>   
<doc>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="title" >Product Title LOLO</field>
<field name="content_type" >parent</field>
<field name="rating_f" >7</field>
    <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="user_id_s" >123</field>
    <field name="userrating_f" >1.2</field>
    </doc>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="title" >Product Title LULU</field>
<field name="content_type" >parent</field>
<field name="rating_f" >2</field>
</doc>

<doc>
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="title" >Product Title LALA</field>
<field name="content_type" >parent</field>
<field name="rating_f" >1.4</field>
    <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="user_id_s" >123</field>
    <field name="userrating_f" >5</field>
    </doc>
</doc>
</add>
```

Question 2 (**The Important one**): How can I query this index now, so that the documents are scored with a boost on the user-rating first (if one exists) and then by the product rating (and then by other fields, like the creation date, views, buys, ...)? Is that even possible?

I was looking into something like that:

```
{!parent which="content_type:parent"}(user_id_s:123 AND _val_:userrating_f)^2.0 _val_:rating_f^2.0 *:*
```

That should return the documents in this order (ids): 3, 1, 2

But instead it returns:

```
      {
    "responseHeader": {
      "status": 500,
      "QTime": 1,
      "params": {
        "indent": "true",
        "q": "{!parent which=\"content_type:parent\"}(user_id_s:123 AND _val_:userrating_f)^2.0 _val_:rating_f^2.0 *:*",
        "_": "1421996862814",
        "wt": "json"
      }
    },
    "error": {
      "msg": "child query must only match non-parent docs, but parent docID=3 matched childScorer=class org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionSumScorer",
      "trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: child query must only match non-parent docs, but parent docID=3 matched childScorer=class org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionSumScorer\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.join.ToParentBlockJoinQuery$BlockJoinScorer.nextDoc(ToParentBlockJoinQuery.java:344)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:192)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.buildAndRunCollectorChain(SolrIndexSearcher.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1619)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1433)\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:514)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:485)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",
      "code": 500
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. there is SolrInputDocument.getChildrenDocs() collection or so. use it.
2. to propagate score from children query to parent ones you need https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5882
3. the problem is that functional queries matches every docs, thus it violates orthogonality and causes the exception. intersect children query with `+content_type:child`